# Sharepoint 2010 Issue Tracking list dates on Sharepoint 2010 Calendar

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar

I would need your help please with SharePoint 2010 Foundation edition.

I have Issue Tracking list where we insert issues and details together with dates (estimations).

And I have Calendar on which I need to make track of this dates (estimated finish date).

Is it possible in SharePoint 2010 to make this automatically? So when I insert an issue and then developer makes an estimation when this will be finished - this is automatically showed in calendar?

Thanks and regards,
Ivo

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this - here it is if someone else needs it.

[Solution for my question - worked for me!](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2013/01/including-list-and-library-items-in-a-sharepoint-2010-calendar-overlay/)

Thanks! 
Ivo